# Only execute MySQL query using indexes

Tags: mysql

I want to execute a SELECT statement on a huge table ONLY if an index (any index) is to be used in execution. I have read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html), but take a look here:

*"You can also use FORCE INDEX, which acts like USE INDEX (index_list) but with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the given indexes to find rows in the table."*

That's not what I want. I want instead of "falling through" to a full table scan, MySQL getting back to me with a certain error/warning/info to tell me explicitly that the query can't be performed because no indexes are available.

Is that PROGRAMMATICALLY possible? What I am actually doing is accepting parameters from a client page, these parameters are basically any columns in the table. So, I want to take these parameters and pass them to the WHERE clause, asking MySQL to perform the resulting query only through indexes.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` and check if index will be used? (but note, this is not a guarantee - there are rare cases when explain and real situation may differ)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say that I want that done programmatically. I added that to the question.

Comment: So that's the issue? You can do that. I.e. query via `EXPLAIN` first. Then, if corresponding column fits your expectations, run query

Answer (score 0):

use `EXPLAIN` on your query and check `key` column

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM users WHERE columnWithIndex = 4
```

your result will look like this:

```
1   SIMPLE  users   ref indexName indexName 8   const   1
```

if key column is not null, sql will use index on your query and you can run it afterwards.